# Pop Up/Message just after embedded signing ceremony is completed - before redirecting to given clientURL

Tags: docusignapi

Is there any way where we can add some message/pop up after embedded signing completed? This message should appear instead of redirecting to clientURL. After closing(pressing continue) on this message, flow should redirect to ClientURL. Is this scenario posssible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow you describe is not possible. i.e., it's not possible to insert a popup window/message in between the DocuSign signing-complete event and the subsequent redirect to the **ClientURL**.

However, if **ClientURL** (i.e., the redirect page) represents a page that you have control over, you could easily build that page with whatever functionality you require -- i.e., it could display a popup window/message before rendering the full page contents.

Comment: Thanks. We started working on this approach yesterday only, convinced stakeholders somehow :). Thanks again.